# Add Product SKU to Product Title in Woocommerce single product page & shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to add product sku to actual product title.
for example, if product name is "Dress design" & product sku is "2790"
the new product title should be "Dress design - 2790".

i had tried following code. but this code replaces the product title by the product SKU on single product pages.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_product_title_by_product_sku', 4 );
function replace_product_title_by_product_sku() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->get_sku() ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_sku_as_title', 5 );
    }
}

function display_product_sku_as_title() {
    global $product;

    echo '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">' . esc_html( $product->get_sku() ) . '</h1>';
}
```

but i want "product title + Sku", & i want to display it on single product page & shop page & checkout page & cart page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you directly change the titles by appending SKU to current titles instead of changing the view only?

```
function append_sku_to_titles() {

 $all_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids'
));

foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
        $_product = wc_get_product( $id );
        $_sku = $_product->get_sku();
        $_title = $_product->get_title();

        $new_title = $_title . " " . $_sku;

        /*
        *   Tested.
        *   echo $_title + $_sku;
        *   echo("<script>console.log('Old: ".$_title. " - ". $_sku."');</script>");
        *   echo("<script>console.log('New: ".$new_title."');</script>");
        */

        $updated = array();
        $updated['ID'] = $id;
        $updated['post_title'] = $new_title;

        wp_update_post( $updated );
}}

//Call the function with footer (*Attention)
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'append_sku_to_titles' );
```

*Attention: Do not forget to remove this line (add_action) after you change the titles since it will try to change them whenever a page loads

Comment: thank you, for your help, i had added this code to my functions.php file. but nothing happens.

Comment: You should call the function, just add " add_action('wp_footer', 'append_sku_to_titles'); " to the functions.php then open your main page, it will change titles. Note: Remove this action after titles are changed, otherwise it will try to change titles everytime a page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this line:

```
echo '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">' . esc_html( $product->get_sku() ) . '</h1>';
```

with:

```
echo '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">' . $product->get_title() . ' - ' . esc_html( $product->get_sku() ) . '</h1>';
```

You are done with it!

Comment: but how to add it on shop page, checkout page & cart page?